# Get consecutive ratios of elements python

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a simple way to get the ratios of consecutive elements of a numpy array?

Basically something similar to numpy.diff(x)?

so if x=[1,2,10,100 ...]

I would like [0.5 ,0.2, 0.1 ...] 
ie [x1/x2, x2/x3 , x3/x4]

I know I can do this easily by shifting and dividing, but it seems clumsy compared to numpy.diff(x)

Comment: You're not going to get anything better than slice-and-divide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
In [6]: x
Out[6]: array([   1.,    2.,   10.,  100.,  150.,   75.])

In [7]: x[:-1]/x[1:]
Out[7]: array([ 0.5       ,  0.2       ,  0.1       ,  0.66666667,  2.        ])
```

That might be what you meant when you said "I can do this easily by shifting and dividing", but I don't see anything clumsy about it.

Comment: Indeed there is nothing clumsy about your syntax x[:-1]/x[1:]  !  Very elegant.

Answer (score 5):

I hate to even post this, but for `x = [6, 2, 4, 10]`,

```
np.exp(-np.diff(np.log(x)))
```

returns `array([3. , 0.5, 0.4])`.

Comment: a working one liner.  Needed to think to understand what you are doing,  clever idea.  @WarrenWeckesser is more intuitive, but this is definitely nice for learning as well as it achieves the result without any shifting.

Comment: I will note that this is about 7x slower than the slicing method: 

    counts = np.random.rand(109) + 1
    import timerit
    ti = timerit.Timerit(10000, bestof=10, verbose=2)
    for timer in ti.reset('time'):
        ratios = counts[:-1] / counts[1:]

    for timer in ti.reset('time'):
        ratios = np.exp(-np.diff(np.log(counts)))

Comment: @Erotemic I'm surprised it's only 7 times, given how expensive `exp` and `log` are. Anyway, I wrote "I hate to even post this" for a reason :)

Answer (score 0):

```
xs = [1, 2, 10, 100, ...]
[x1/x2 for (x1, x2) in zip(xs, xs[1:])]
```